# search a word and highlight it using php

Tags: php, search, cpu-word, highlight, using

my question is i wants to find a word in given string and background change of that word on each click of button and counter is increases just like a search next in any editor.

```
<?php 

function writeMsg()
{
$str = "my bird is funny, we fun are funny,they are     funny they are fun";
$keyword =$_GET['search'];
$strarr=explode(" ",$str);
//print_r($strarr);

    foreach ($strarr as $val) 
    {
   //print_r($val); 
   if($val==$keyword)
   {echo hi;
   $copy_date = preg_replace("/$keyword\b/",'<b     style=background-color:yellow;>'.$keyword.'</b>',   $val);
   print $copy_date;   
   }
   else
   {
   echo $val;  
   }    }
//}
?>
<html>
    <form action="#" method="get">
    Please enter word to search<input type="text"   name="search"><br/>
<input type="button" value="NEXT"   onclick="document.write('<?php 'writeMsg()';?>');" />

    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: php runs server side - that is, before the html arrives all the php processing has been done. So you need to use something like JavaScript to get a function that interacts with the user in the way you want. Would that be an acceptable alternative for you (you are specifically asking about php…)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: better.... use <span>  </span>

Comment: Do you want all words highlighted with one click of the button; add one more highlight per click; or move the highlight to the next item?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using regex, `str_replace()` will do just fine. It even has a built in counter.

```
<?php 
function writeMsg(){
    $count = 0;
    $str = "my bird is funny, we fun are funny, they are funny they are fun";
    $keyword = $_GET['search'];
    $str = str_replace($keyword, "<b style='background-color:yellow;'>".$keyword."</b>",$str,$count);
    echo "There were ".$count." matches.<br />";
    echo $str;
}
?>
<html>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
        Please enter word to search: <input type="text" name="search"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="NEXT" />
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        writeMsg();
    }
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Upvoting this one since it actually shows how to call the server to do the php processing.

Comment: The substitution works for sure. but what happens if the keyword in a link?  e.g. <a href='keyword.htm'>here is my keyword</a>

It is going to break the link

Comment: @Adelphia, oh well then, let's just give him some code that has a potential hidden flaw in it.

Comment: a simple question deserves a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just `str_replace` function like this.

```
<?php
$str = "my bird is funny, we fun are funny,they are     funny they are fun";
$str1=$str;

echo $str."<br/>";


$find="funny"; 
$str=str_replace($find,'<span style="color:red">'.$find.'</span>',$str);

echo $str."<br/>"; //If keyword exists displays updated string

$find="funky"; 
$str=str_replace($find,'<span style="color:red">'.$find.'</span>',$str1);

echo $str; //If keyword doesn't exist, Just display the same string
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Javascript implementation:

```
String:  <input type = "text" id = "mystring">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id = "mystringdiv" style="width:400px; height:120px; border:solid black 1px;"></div>

Word to search: <input type = "text" id = "searchstring"><input type = "button" value = "Search" onclick = "startSearch()">

<script type = "text/javascript">
function startSearch()
{
    var search = new RegExp(document.getElementById("searchstring").value, "g")
    var string = document.getElementById("mystring").value

    var nstring = string.replace(search, "<b style=\"background-Color:#FFFF00\">"+document.getElementById("searchstring").value+"</b>")

    document.getElementById("mystringdiv").innerHTML=nstring

}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dRW84/

Comment: Why was this voted down?  Javascript seems like a better choice than using PHP as it will not require a form submission or an AJAX call to process the input and highlighting.

Comment: I think this is actually worth an up vote, not a down vote. JS is almost certainly the right way to do this - although I am not sure that your code doesn't highlight all the matches at once instead of "once per click". But the question was ambiguous on that point.

Comment: It does work with all of the matches, hence the "g" in the RegExp for "global".  Test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/dRW84/

Comment: Sorry about the double negative: I meant to say "I think it highlights all the matches at once, instead of one more on each click". "I'm not sure it doesn't" is logically not the same as "I am sure it does", but you get the idea.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP and what will happen if the keyword is within a link, or happens to be an element name or anything else in the source code of a page?

Comment: It's only rewriting the string you give it, not the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far fail to address what happens if the keyword is used in a link.

Here is my solution.  It may not be perfect, but it allows for this.

```
//this code will highlight the search string in the returned search results.  It ignores text within tags

function doHighlight ($strneedle, $strhaystack){

//this fixes bug if first char is a <
if(strpos($strhaystack,"<")==0) {$strhaystack = " " . $strhaystack;}

$strhaystack = str_replace("\"","'",$strhaystack);
$newthought = "";
$i = 0;
    //only do it if we have a tag
    $findtag = strpos($strhaystack,"<");

    if ($findtag > 0){

        //count how many tags we have 
        $strCount = substr_count( $strhaystack,"<");

        //and loop that many times
        while($i < $strCount){
            $i++;
            //find opening tag
            $pos = strpos( $strhaystack,"<");
            //get text to left of opening tag
            $thoughtstart = substr($strhaystack , 0, $pos);
                //highlight that text
                $pattern = $strneedle;
                $replacement = '<span class="highlight">'.$strneedle.'</span>';
                $highlightedthought = eregi_replace($pattern, $replacement, $thoughtstart);
                //build the new string
                $newthought = $newthought . $highlightedthought;

            //find closing tag and concatenate it to new string without highlighting
            $thoughtremainder = substr($strhaystack, $pos);
                $pos = strpos( $thoughtremainder,">");
                $thoughtstart = substr($thoughtremainder , 0, $pos);
                $newthought = $newthought . $thoughtstart;      

            //make the rest of the thought the new string and loop
            $strhaystack = substr($thoughtremainder, $pos); 
        }
    }
    //if no tag, return the highlighted thought
    else{
        $pattern = $strneedle;
        $replacement = '<span class="highlight">'.$strneedle.'</span>';
        $newthought = eregi_replace($pattern, $replacement, $strhaystack);
        }

return (trim($newthought));
}
```